# Can we configure users in Jenkins to only view build history for jobs submitted by them

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have 3 users in Jenkins

1. Admin User - Has the complete access of Jenkins
2. Developer - Has complete access to create/edit/view/delete Jobs
3. Tester - Has access to only view/run Jobs

We want to build a capability where Developer & Tester should be able to only view build history of jobs submitted by him/her but Admin should be able to view build history of jobs submitted by all users.

Please guide as I am new to Jenkins.